# How do I require Tkinter with distutils?

Tags: python, tkinter, distutils

I'm trying to compile a program using `distutils` but I want to make sure that the user has Tkinter installed before installing my package.

My Google searches have failed to turn up any useful info, any clue how I'd do this?

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a class that inherits from `install` and then do this:

```
from distutils.command.install import install

class Install(install):
    def run(self):
        if not check_dependencies():
             # Tkinter was not installed, handle this here
        install.run(self) # proceed with the installation

def check_dependencies():
    try:
        return __import__('Tkinter')
    except ImportError:
        return None
```

Comment: And yes, Tkinter is in the standard library.

Comment: Though on some platforms (Ubuntu) it's not installed by default.

Comment: Wayne, I am on 10.10 and it is installed by default. Also, it's part of the stdlib, so if Python is there, it should be there too right? When was it included in the stdlib? I don't know, so maybe that can be the problem. Anyways, the above solution should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no standard cross-platform way to force `Tkinter` to be installed.  `Tkinter` is part of the Python standard library so distributors who strip out `Tkinter`, or other standard library modules, and package them as optional entities are doing so using their own package management tools and, in general, you'd need to know the specific commands for each distribution.  The best you can do in general is test for and fail gracefully if `Tkinter` (or `tkinter` in `Python 3`) is not importable, so something like:

```
import sys
try:
    import Tkinter
except ImportError:
    sys.exit("Tkinter not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is in the [python standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html), it should **always** be there.

Comment: As I mentioned on sukhbir's post - it's not installed by default on Ubuntu - you have to install the `python-tk` package. At least *last* time I installed Ubuntu it wasn't.